# How to make a correct rotation? popover in Swift/Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, popover

How to make a correct rotation?

xCode setting

[image: xCode setting]

show popover

[image: show popover]

after rotation

[image: after rotation]

Comment: I still dont understand what you want to do. Please explain.

Comment: after rotation screen popover not centered (bug rotation - image)
i want (correct rotation - image)

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1694/_index.html)

> In the -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method of UIApplication,
>   present the popover controller again after the rotation has finished.

Comment: You have to hide the popover and present it again

Comment: it should close? Give an example

Answer (score 0):

You can just manage it yourself. add a listener:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(onRotate:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
object:nil];
```

Then write the `onRotate:` function which will control the popover.
The relevant parameters for your problem are **rect** and **view**.
For your green square it should be enough. Your function will look like this: (I understand you want the green popover in the center of the screen)

```
-(void)onRotate {
   ZAVsPopover.rect.origin.x = (ZAVsPopover.view.rect.size.width - ZAVsPopover.rect.size.width)/2;
   ZAVsPopover.rect.origin.y = (ZAVsPopover.view.rect.size.height - ZAVsPopover.rect.size.height)/2;
}
```

Comment: what type of object it ZAVsPopover?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

Make sure the view controller presenting the popover conforms to UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate.

Example:

```
class MyViewContoller: UIVIewContoller, UIPUIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate 
{

// your code...

// MARK: UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate Methods

func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>) {
    let viewFrame = popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.view.frame
    let deltaX = viewFrame.height - rect.pointee.midX
    let deltaY = viewFrame.width - rect.pointee.midY
    rect.pointee = CGRect(x: viewFrame.width - deltaX, y: viewFrame.height - deltaY, width: 0, height: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you'll need to dismiss your popover in
`viewWillTransition`

method, and show again after a delay. Don't forget set new size to `popoverPresentationController.sourceRect`.

Code:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if let popover = self.presentedViewController as? UIViewController {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            if let weakSelf = self {
                popover.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(),
                                                                           size: size)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        weakSelf.present(weakSelf.popover, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```